# Tensorflow: ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I recently started learning Tensorflow and am following this guide.
https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

I am attempting to use my own data sheet with two labels as well (car and not car).

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)


X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
model.save('car.model')
```

However, I'm getting an error that I do not understand how to fix.

```
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 8406
  y sizes: 0
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Appreciate the help!